# What could cause a knocking noise front drivers side?

Tags: noise, vw, suspension, polo, accelerator

I have a VW Polo. The knocking noise can be heard from the front drivers side when going at slow speeds. The noise can mainly only be heard when going over any sort of bumps. The knocking can be felt in the accelerator sometimes.
We have replaced the shocks but it doesnt seem to have fixed the problem.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: There could be several causes for this, ranging from motor mounts to suspension to CV joints. Are you able to reproduce the noise easily?